# Cauchy-like functional equation

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

I came across this question from some Olympiad training material,
which has a strong likeness to Cauchy functional equations:

> Find all functions $f : \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z,x) = f(0,x+y+z)$

My questions:

- How to get rid of the extra dimension, it looks like $f(x,y)=f(0,y)=g(y)$ but how it can be shown
- How to reduce the given condition from 3 variables to 2.

Comment: It seems like plugging $x = y = 0$ in gives you $f(z,0) = - f(0,0)$ for all $z$, and so, by having $z = 0$, we get $f(0,0) = -f(0,0) = 0$, and as such $f(z,0) = 0$ for all $z$. Then, by plugging $y = 0$, we have: $f(0,z) + f(z,x) = f(0,x+z)$, but I don't know if that's useful yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working in $\mathbb Q$ is a strong hint that you must divide and conquer.

As proven by **Bruno B** in the comments, $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$. Then:

1. Plug $(x,y,0)$ to get $f(x,y)=f(0,x+y)-f(0,x)$. From this point on, forget about $f$ altogether. Let's just work with $g(x)=f(0,x)$.
2. By expressing $f$ via $g$, out equation turns into $g(x+y)+g(x+z)+g(y+z)-g(x)-g(y)-g(z)=g(x+y+z)$. This kind of says that the third order *finite difference derivative* of $g$ is $0$, so $g(x)$ must be a quadratic polynomial. But if we feel the urge to be really rigorous, proceed to the following steps.
3. Plug $(x,x,x)$ to get $g(3x)=3g(2x)-3g(x)$
4. Plug $(2x,x,x)$ to get $g(4x)=2g(3x)+g(2x)-g(2x)-2g(x)=6g(2x)-8g(x)$
5. Plug $(3x,x,x)$ to get $g(5x)=2g(4x)+g(2x)-g(3x)-2g(x)=10g(2x)-15g(x)$
6. Figure out (not necessarily as slow as I did) that $g(nx)={n^2-n\over2}g(2x)-(n^2-2n)g(x)\tag1$ Prove by induction.
7. Plug $x\over n$ to express $g(x)$ and $g(2x)$ via $g({x\over n})$ and $g({2x\over n})$, then reverse that expression to find out that **(1)** is true not only for integer $n$, but for aliquot fractions as well.
8. Go from $g(x)$ to $g({x\over q})$, then to $g({px\over q})$ to prove that **(1)** actually holds true for **any rational number** in place of $n$.
9. Finally,
   $$g(x)=ax^2+bx\tag2$$
   $$f(x,y)=a(y^2+2xy)+by\tag3$$

Comment: I struggle with understanding steps 7 and 8. Doing the plug I get $g(x) = \frac{n^2-n}{2} g(\frac{2x}{n}) - (n^2-2n)g(\frac{x}{n})$ and I don't know how to deal with the $g(\frac{2x}{n})$ term. Am I supposed to arrive at a result like $g( \frac{x}{n} ) = \frac{(\frac{1}{n})^2-\frac{1}{n}}{2}g(2x)-((\frac{1}{n})^2-2\frac{1}{n})g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, like that. To get another equation, plug $x\over n$ instead of $x$ and $2n$ instead of $n$. That would give you $g(2x)$ in terms of $g(x/n)$ and $g(2x/n)$.

Comment: I am still lost. What would the substituted equation look like? And I suppose it takes a lot of algebraic manipulation to get to the desired result? Do I need to rearrange to put $g(\frac{x}{n})$ first? Like $g(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{1}{2n^2-n} (g(x) + (4n^2-4n)g(\frac{x}{2n}))$

Comment: The substituted equation would be $g(2x) = \frac{(2n)^2-2n}{2} g(\frac{2x}{n}) - ((2n)^2-2\cdot2n)g(\frac{x}{n})$. The rest is no more advanced than something like $$\begin{cases}5a+3b&=11\\7a-2b&=3,\\ \end{cases}$$ except that you have some algebraic expressions in place of "5", "3", "11", etc. Also, you _already know_ the end result.